# Convert integer latitude and longitude to decimal (using for google maps api)

Tags: c#, google-maps, geolocation, latitude-longitude

Currently I'm trying to convert integer `latitude` and `longitude` to decimal (degrees). The specification from where I get the data says:

> | Latitude | Position latitude | Integer, number of 1/10th of a second  |
>
> | Longitude | Position longitude | Integer, number of 1/10th of a second  |

Here is a sample number:

- Latitude: `1914383`
- Longitude: `371352`

What I need, is something in this format:

- Latitude: `51.39796`
- Longitude: `14.62539`

How can I convert those formats?

I've seen a few implementations in c#, but nothing that was really usable for me, or I don't get how this might work. What I've tried:

[Converting GPS coordinates (latitude and longitude) to decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557684/converting-gps-coordinates-latitude-and-longitude-to-decimal)
and [Converting latitude and longitude to decimal values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140189/converting-latitude-and-longitude-to-decimal-values)

Thanks a lot

Comment: As it is given in 1/10 sec, just divide it by 36000. Check how sign is forming in the API documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for the conversions between formats.

```
    private void ConvertSampleFunction()
    {
        //let N 40264600 be a GPS coordinate. Then
        //Format in degrees minutes seconds: 40° 26′ 46″ N 
        double Degs=40.0;
        double Mins=26.0;
        double Secs=46.00;
        //Then in degrees - decimal minutes Format will be
        double Ddegs=Degs;
        double Dmins=Mins;
        double Dsecs=Secs/60.0;
        //This will give Ddegs and Dmins.Dsecs e.g. 40 degrees and 26.767'
        //and In Decimal format DDD.DDD... it will be
        double DecDegs=Degs+Mins/60.0+Secs/3600.0;
        //which will give the value 40.446..
    }
```

Hope these help.